# How to add a weight to a pairing when calculating the distance between two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

In my application I have to calculate the distance between two vectors, each of which is contained of points ranging from -1 to 1. For example, the distance between these two vectors:

```
 .75     .06
 .20    -.44
-.95     .17
-.32     .85
 .04    -.12
```

is calculated by taking the absolute value of the difference between each pairing, like so:

```
 abs(.75  -   .06) = 0.69
 abs(.20  -  -.44) = 0.64
abs(-.95  -   .17) = 1.12
abs(-.32  -   .85) = 1.17
 abs(.04  -  -.12) = 0.16
```

They are then summed and divided by the count:

```
(.69 + 0.64 + 1.12 + 1.17 + 0.16) / 5 = 0.756
```

The distance ranges from `-1` to `1`, which is a property I need to maintain.

This all works well and good, but I'd like to impose an additional constraint of weighting. For example, I'd like the third pairing `(-0.95, .17)` to be worth, say, 3x as much as the others. I'm not sure how to change the algorithm to account for this.

I can't just multiply it by 3, because then the result is no longer in the range `[-1, 1]`, and this must be up-held. Apologies if this has a trivial answer, I'm really bad at math.

Also, just to clarify, I'll need to weight multiple pairings, each with arbitrary amounts (for example: the first pairing weighted 2x, the third pairing weighted 0.5x, the fouth pairing weighted 4x, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your $\Delta$'s are in $[0,2]$, in order to get a weighted distance in $[0,2]$, you should divide by the sum of the contribitions of all the factors, so
$$ d = 1/(w_x + w_y + ...) (w_x \Delta x + w_y \Delta y + ...) $$

Further, why are negative distances allowed? A negative distance cannot be obtained with a valid metric.

Comment: Well, feel free to think of the range as between 0 and 2 instead of -1 and 1 if it helps. I just need to be able to convert the distance to within that range by the end. And I am using the [Manhattan Distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095027/697869) right now. I asked someone else a while ago and they recommended that. I forget their exact reasons.

Comment: Okay, Manhattan Distance sounds good, but the problem of this is that it is not bounded (, the Euclidian distance isn't bounded either, so no problem there). Because it is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ the only way to make it fit in the $[0, 2]$ interval is using by bounding the space, so putting limit on where you can put your vectors. Once this is done and the maximum manhattan distance with 3 times the distance along the y-axis is e.g. 10. Then dividing the distance by a constant factor, e.g.:
$$d = 1/5 (\Delta x + 3\Delta y + \Delta z + ...)$$ will get you in the interval.

Comment: So you're saying I just need to keep track of all my weightings, sum them up, and divide by them at the end? For example: `d = 1/12(4Δr+3Δs+1Δt+2Δu+1Δv+0.5Δw+0.5Δx)`?

Comment: Yes, but it all depends on how big your  vectors may become, can I submit a vector (1000, 100000, 1000) or are there limits?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. All Δx values will be between `[-1, 1]` and the weights will be between 0x and 10x. The number of pairings is unbounded, but probably around 100-500 in most cases.

Comment: Ah, oké, all values $x \in [-1, 1]$, so all values $\Delta x \in [0, 2]$. So, to get the distance in $[0,2]$, it is indeed sufficient to just divide be sum of the weightings like you said above, this will result in $d \in [0, 2]$.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try this strategy out. Hope it works! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I only now see that the fact that they are all between -1 and 1 was in the question. I missed it when reading it. I'll update my answer to the conclusion of this conversation.